# How do you access a JavaScript variable inside a Rails escape_javascript line?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view

Say I'm inside a JavaScript function, I'd like access to data within the Rails line like this:

```
var DATA_USED
html = "<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'change_date_range', :locals => {:end_date_string => DATA_USED }) %>";
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't make much sense. The JavaScript code runs in the client browser, and there'll be no trace of the Rails code there; it's all run on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should use AJAX (I recommend [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)) for this.  You'll want to have JS send a request back to your Rails server with the JavaScript variable as a param in the request.